# AVPlayer not going to the next song when it is in background mode

Tags: ios7, avplayer

I am useing AVPlayer to play setof songs from urls. I can play songs in background mode too. But the problem is in background mode the next song is not playing. It excecute the code and but [player play]; method is not working. But If play 1 song it plays to the end though it goes to the background mode.

Please help me
Thanks

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/29948/backgrounding-for-ios

Comment: I red this but I dont know inside this if else what should I do,, if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState] == UIApplicationStateActive) {
            self.lblMusicTime.text = timeString;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"App is backgrounded. Time is: %@", timeString);
        }

Answer (score 1):

You should use `AVQueuePlayer` instead. This is working fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you probably have this figured out by now, but for anyone else who might come across this, try putting this in your viewDidLoad:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginReceivingRemoteControlEvents];
```

Assuming you have this :

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

in your AppDelegate.m, under didFinishLaunch and your info.plist set up to play audio in the background.

Had the same problem, and this solved it for me.