# Play Audio from URL ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio

> I am developing application like gaana.com
>
> Which player can be used for play mp3 songs from server url ? I want
>   to implement Play, Pause, Next, Previous buttons And will also play
>   song list in background mode one by one.
>
> I have already implemented AVPlayer but i getting issue in playing
>   next audio in background mode. And i had tried all answers regarding
>   this issue but none of all is working for me.

So i am finding alternative of AVPlayer.

Comment: What issue are you experiencing, what error is being thrown? The more information you provide us the bigger the chances are that we can provide a solid answer.

Comment: I have Same issue in AVPlayer, Given in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20965422/avplayer-not-going-to-the-next-song-when-it-is-in-background-mode

Comment: if you need next button click to move next mp3?

Comment: No next song automatically start playing on end of current song.

Comment: if your app start the play first song finally the current song stoped ah?its the problem ah?

Comment: No

My app working fine in foreground mode

I have issue in playing song in background mode
When 1 song end playing in background mode than it should automatically start playing next song but its not working in background. Same code working fine in foreground

Comment: if you set the Capabilities background mode in your app?

Comment: Yes, I also set this lines

NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
    NSError *activationErr  = nil;
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory: AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&setCategoryErr];
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];